# Swift: how to change a integer variable name within a method and reassign its value

Tags: swift

I am a complete beginner at Swift/programming and am making a noughts and crosses app as part of an online course. I wanted to do this on my own before I saw the solution so my logic may be a bit weird.

I have a function which is called each time a button is pressed (there are 9, one for each square). The function acts to:
i) update the number of turns (which allows me to see who's go it is)
ii) change the picture to X or O
iii) deactivate the button after each turn
iv) calculate is anyone has won by changing the value of that squares potential lines. The numbers I have chosen to do this are 3 and 4 (for noughts and crosses), hence the c = 3 or 4 below. This means that if any winning line adds up to 9 or 12, the game stops as someone has won.

I have 9 variables (Int) that hold the score for each square - they are a1o, a2o, a3o, b1o... i.e all end in "o". In the function I want to add the string of "a1" in front of the "o", meaning each button is only relevant to itself with only one line of code above the function (within the button parentheses).

The function looks like this at the moment; calling it by: button(a1, buttonValue: "a1")

```
    func button(buttonName: UIButton, buttonValue: NSString) -> String {

            let a = buttonName
            var b = buttonValue

            b = (b as String) + "o"
            print(b)
            // the above prints "a1o", the name of the variable, but it is a string...

            index += 1
            print("Go number \(index)")

            if index % 2 == 0 {

                // show a nought

                a.setImage(UIImage(named: "nought.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

                c = 3
                // the above line doesn't work as its a string, but I am attempting to set the squares value to 3 (i.e. a1o = 3)

                winner()

                a.userInteractionEnabled = false


            } else {

                // show a cross

                a.setImage(UIImage(named: "cross.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

                c = 4 
                // the above line doesn't work as its a string

                winner()

                a.userInteractionEnabled = false

            }

            return "done"

        }
```

What I can't figure out is how to change the common stem of the variable *a1*o by not making it a string, or if I do, how I convert it back to a variable.

I am struggling with definitions and as a result looking for an answer has been hard. The variable a1o is an integer, but how do I refer to a1o itself?

Thank you in advance,

Sam

Comment: Enumerating variables by adding numbers or some kind of dynamic naming indicator is almost always a bad idea - simply because **you cannot get a variable dynamically via its name**. Whenever you talk about indices or anything related your best bet is to use arrays instead. In your case why not create a two dimensional array of size 3x3 (guessing tic-tac-toe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **not possible** to access variables dynamically by name like you want to do. However, there are better ways to accomplish the same goal. How about a two-dimensional array?

```
var scores: [[Int]] = [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]
scores[0][1] = 4 //this is the new version of "a2o = 4"
```

Unlike with variable names, the indices to the array ("0" and "1" in this case) **can** be dynamically chosen. Or, if you really want to keep your buttons' values exactly the same, you could use a dictionary:

```
var scores: [String: Int] = [:]
scores[buttonValue as String] = 4
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andy and Luk.    I didn't know you could have two dimensional arrays, but that is definitely a more elegant solution than mine.  I managed to figure out a way to get around it, by using an inout parameter. That way I could introduce the variable at any value and it would leave with another, leaving the "xxo" variable with a number. the function is now:       `func button(buttonName: UIButton, inout buttonValue: Int)`    And I access it, eg for a1o:    `button(a1, buttonValue: &a1o)`